# can we share screen through socket.io without select screen prompt

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, webrtc, socket.io-client

i want chose my screen and share it on socket.io server but without any select screen pop up
form browser
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true }).then((stream: MediaStream) => {

Answer (score 2):

This pop-up is a security/privacy mechanism that lets the user control what they want to share. It can not be worked around by a web page.